# Programmatically Add a Reference to a Visual Studio Project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I want to programmatically add references to Visual Studio projects. This is for creating an add in tool to Visual Studio. What I want to do is use an API of some sort. What I don't want to deal with is just editing the XML of the project file (.csproj, .vbproj).

Is there any knowledge out there on how to do this? I couldn't find anything here or on google that answered this scenario...

Related, but this is not my question: [Updating Visual Studio project references programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080625/updating-visual-studio-project-references-programatically)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So apparently you can get to the DTE to add references. :D